# Recompile on save isn't working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, compilation, recompile

I started a Node.js project on Visual Studio 2017 Community on my PC at home, just to test a few things out and play around.

When I begin "debugging" (as in get Visual Studio to compile and launch the website), any changes I make and save to files are not reflected until I restart the entire debugging process. I've Node.js projects through Visual Studio on other computers, and they seemed to recompile the individual files as they were saved, reflecting any changes immediately. I can't seem to find anything online that would suggest a solution, I guess Visual Studio/node.js is a pretty rare combination.

My Visual Studio Community 2017 installation on Windows 10 is fairly slim. In terms of components:

- Cloud, database, and server:

  - Connectivity and publishing tools
  - Web Deploy
- Code tools: Developer Analytics tools
- Debugging and testing: JavaScript diagnostics
- Development activities:

  - JavaScript and TypeScript language support
  - Node.js support
- SDKs, libraries, and frameworks: TypeScript 2.5 SDK

**Would anyone how I can make Visual Studio recompile each file on save while debugging?** It's definitely possible, I'm probably just missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since figured that this is not native functionality for VisualStudio to recompile each time an application-dependent file is changed. There are, however, packages available that can allow Node to do this, such as [Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).